# Create button to download vcard and open contacts app

Tags: google-chrome, velo

I have a button in WIX, it downloads a vcard and I want that it open the contacts app.
With Safari it's works fine, with Android no, it downloads the file but don't open the contacts app.
Any ideas please?

Comment: It's probably not related to your site, but your phone and how it treats vcard files.

Comment: It’s a way ti resolve it?

Comment: If you download the **same card** using android is it working?

Comment: did you find any solution of it ? how did you open contacts app in ios